# How to generate different data on row from arrays in different sections of uitableview cell

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have some database and I am generating data something like this.

First getting categoryid and categoryName form the database. And sectiontitle of the table is categoryName.

here is some sample code

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return categoryNamesList.count;
}

-(NSString *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [categoryNamesList objectAtIndex:section];   

}
```

I want to generate flashcardid and flashcard name on the base of category id. categoryid is stored in database like 1,2,3.

So I'm passing categoryid in query:

```
select flashCardId,flashCardName from flashCardInfo where categoryId=(parameter)
```

In the flashcardid I am getting 1,2,3 and in the flashcards names array I am getting flashcard1,flashcard2,flashcard3  first time now I want to generate text on my cell like firstcategoryname on section 1 and then related flashcard name on the rows then on the second section second category name and related flashcardsNames on the rows. Where to increase the category id so that I get next names nad id's and how to set text on cells

now how do I generate this on

Here is the code; it's in the `indexviewcontroller.m` file.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return categoryNamesList.count;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {  

    return flashCardsNamesList.count;       

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";  
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];  
if (cell == nil) {      
    cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];      
}


    if(categoryID<listOfCategoryId.count)
    {   
        for(int i=0;i<flashCardsNamesList.count;i++)
        {
        [cell.FlashCardsNames setText:[flashCardsNamesList objectAtIndex:i]];
        }       
    categoryID++;
    [self getFlashCard:categoryID];
    }           
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [indexTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    for(int i=0;i<flashCardsId.count;i++)
    {
            questionViewControllerObj = [[flashCardQuestionViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FlashCardQuestionView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:questionViewControllerObj animated:YES];                  
            questionViewControllerObj.flashcardid = [[flashCardsId objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
            questionViewControllerObj.categoryid = [[listOfCategoryId objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]intValue];
    }

}


/*
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    }
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
    }
}
*/
/*
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}
*/
/*
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
}
*/
/*
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}
*/

-(NSString *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [categoryNamesList objectAtIndex:section];   

}

# pragma mark -
# pragma mark viewDidLoad

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];    
    [self getIntialData];
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Index";
    indexTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];  
}


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Database Methods


-(void)getIntialData
{
    [self getcategory];
    [self getFlashCard:categoryID]; 

}
  //getting categoryid,categoryname from the database
-(void)getcategory
{
    if(listOfCategoryId!=nil)
        [listOfCategoryId removeAllObjects];
    else
        listOfCategoryId = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    if(categoryNamesList!=nil)
        [categoryNamesList removeAllObjects];
    else
        categoryNamesList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    if(listOfCategoryType!=nil)
        [listOfCategoryType removeAllObjects];
    else
        listOfCategoryType = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    clsDatabase *clsDatabaseObject = [[clsDatabase alloc] init];
    sqlite3_stmt *dataRows = [clsDatabaseObject getDataset:"select categoryId,categoryName,categoryType from cardCategoryInfo"];
    while(sqlite3_step(dataRows) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {       
        [listOfCategoryId addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:sqlite3_column_int(dataRows,0)]];
        [categoryNamesList addObject: [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(dataRows,1)]] ;
        [listOfCategoryType addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:sqlite3_column_int(dataRows,2)]];
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(dataRows);
    [clsDatabaseObject release];    
    categoryID = [[listOfCategoryId objectAtIndex:categoryID] intValue];
}


   //getting flashcardId and flashcard name from categoryid
-(void)getFlashCard:(int)categoryid
{
    if(flashCardsId!=nil)
        [flashCardsId removeAllObjects];
    else
        flashCardsId = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    if(flashCardsNamesList!=nil)
        [flashCardsNamesList removeAllObjects];
    else
        flashCardsNamesList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];



    NSString *martialStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", categoryid];

    NSString *queryStr=[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"select flashCardId,flashCardName from flashCardInfo where categoryId="];
    queryStr=[queryStr stringByAppendingString:martialStr];


    unsigned int lengthOfString=[queryStr length];
    char temp2[lengthOfString +1];
    strcpy(temp2, [queryStr cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);    
    clsDatabase *clsDatabaseObject = [[clsDatabase alloc] init];    
    sqlite3_stmt *dataRows = [clsDatabaseObject getDataset:temp2];
    while(sqlite3_step(dataRows) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {       
        [flashCardsId addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:sqlite3_column_int(dataRows,0)]];       
        [flashCardsNamesList addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(dataRows,1)]];    

    }
    sqlite3_finalize(dataRows);
    [clsDatabaseObject release];

}

- (void)dealloc {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [listOfCategoryId release];
    [listOfCategoryType release];
    [questionViewControllerObj release];
    [categoryNamesList release];
    [flashCardsNamesList release];
    [flashCardsId release];
    [indexTableView release];   
    [super dealloc];
}



@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement cellForRowAtIndexPath to fill in the rows in each table section.

e.g.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  // This method gets called for each section and row in your table
  NSUInteger cellRow = [indexPath row];
  NSUInteger cellSection = [indexPath section];

  // Create new table cell
  // Deliberately ignoring reusing cells to keep this example simple
  UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"] autorelease];

  // Now build up a string with the info you want in it based on
  // data in cellSection and cellRow, and set the cell text
  cell.text = @"put your text here";
```

Update: If you want somebody to write all your code for you you'll need to edit your post to be shorter and more clear. Just explain what data structures you have, and what the table should look like, e.g.

```
DATA STRUCTURES 

-NSDictionary of section names as keys. 
-Each NSDictionary key points at an NSArray, which holds NSStrings that need to go in each row. 

DESIRED OUTPUT 

section 0 heading 
row 0 
row 1 

section 1 heading 
row 0 
row 1
```

etc

Comment: It would help if you defined your example arrays in code.  I've updated my response to request more info.

Comment: i want the same thing as you written above.i am editing the question with my code to give you detailed infeormation

Answer (score 1):

To reuse cells

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]  initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"] autorelease];
}
// Configure the cell
...
return cell;
```